# Database: How to check on values before deletion?

Tags: database

I have a database with the following tables:

Table Order:

- @id
- Date
- State (can have this values ('payed', 'open))
- Customer (references Customer(id))

Table Customer:

- @id
- name

Now I have to make sure that I only can delete a customer, who doesn't have orders with status 'open'.

Is there any solution without creating a trigger? But if not... how must the trigger looks like?

Answer (score 0):

From a database consistency point of view, you probably don't want to delete any customers who have placed an order without also deleting the order. If you allow the deletion of customers who have "paid" orders, your "orders" table has records for which you can't find the customer; this in turn means that you need to remember to do outer joins every time you query the orders and customers table together.

If the above is true, you can use your database engine's referential integrity constraints to enforce that rule.

If the above is not true, you can, indeed, implement a trigger. You don't mention your RDBMS engine, so the syntax will vary, but you need to create a trigger on the "delete" event for customers, and check that the deleted:id isn't found in the orders table where status not "open".